# browser form must launch PHP script that disconnects and runs in background

Tags: php, command-line, exec, background-process

I have a PHP routine that runs correctly with query/GET data from the browser, and I would like to disconnect it from the browser after it is launched so it can run in the background. It writes a file to disk and emails the link to the user, so it no longer needs the browser.

The iframe path launched by the browser looks like this

```
src="tool/scan.php?types=All&order=Newest&email=test@example.com"
```

I will replace the iframe target with a middleman that will pass everything through to the `scan.php` workhorse file.

I understand `exec()` can be used, but apparently don't understand exactly how to format the command line and have been befuddled by the resources I have found thus far.

I tried just passing the $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]. path/filename .  $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] through verbatim, but that doesn't seem to work (echo shows the value in quotes below):

```
exec("/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/tool/scan.php?types=All&order=Newest&email=test@example.com");
```

So then I wondered if command line differs from browser params and tried this, but that's not it either

```
exec("/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/tool/scan.php types=All order=Newest email=test@example.com");
```

I just need a tip in the right direction to get rolling again if anyone can provide a pointer. I'm not too PHP literate and don't read tomes well, but I can usually make my way around most obstacles with a few well-placed hints. Thanks...

Comment: thats not how you parse arguments in the cli envirmoment

Comment: cli envirmoment -- that means "command line interface"? You see my problem then?

Comment: those exec lines, if you want to pass arguments to the script you put them on the command line like `scan.php All Newest test@example.com` and in the file access them the array $argv http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to create a *Message Queue*.  So the script that accepts the form post submits the data to the message queue. The message queue can be a table in a MySQL database that holds the data to be processed. Then you have a cron service that's running every few minutes or so that will pull all of the messages out of the queue and process them.

If you want to run PHP in the `exec()` function with $_GET parameters you can do it this way:

```
exec('php-cgi -f /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/tool/scan.php types=All order=Newest email=test@example.com');
```

Or this way:

```
exec('wget "http://example.com/tool/scan.php?types=All&order=Newest&email=test@example.com"');
```

Comment: chrislondon, thank you for the suggestions, but there is no MySQL, just unix.

Comment: oh ok @user2507595 I've added a couple `exec()`s you could do. If the script waits for them to finish try adding a ` &` at the end so it would be `exec('php-cgi ... &');`

Comment: chrislondon, OK, I will experiment with your suggestions. Thank you. I must learn what "wget" and "php-cgi" mean in this context.

Comment: exec runs command line functions. `wget` is a unix command line function that can make calls to web pages.  `php-cgi` is the cgi version of php

Comment: "If the script waits for them to finish" -- The script just does its own thing and writes a file. Is the `&` for returning a value? IF so, then it is not needed. The wget looks very attractive. I'll explore.

Comment: I tried `wget` because it seemed the simplest to implement with my knowledge and existing code and it works. Just had to be careful to get all the quotes in place.  I now receive the email file. Thank you very much.